# Change width and height of column using ExcelPackage

Tags: c#, excel, nopcommerce, excelpackage

I'm writing some code for my NopCommerce webshop, that needs to export an excel sheet.

I'm trying to edit the width of the columns, so the text will fit in.
I already tried the following code(for 26 columns):

```
//adjust excel column width
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    worksheet.Column(i, 1).Width = 45;
}
```

The code executes and the Width of the columns is 45, so you could say it works.
But it gives me the following error at start up:

[image: xlsx error]

How can I get rid of this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `worksheet.Column(i).Width = 45;` ?